# Netbeans: Fix Imports vs Organize Imports

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

In the Netbeans IDE, what precisely do the 'Fix Imports' and 'Organize Imports' do?

I have recently migrated from Eclipse, and I find the wording somewhat confusing.  'Fix Imports' in Netbeans seems to have the same function as 'Organize Imports' did in Eclipse.  If this is the case, what is the function of the 'Organize Imports'?

I have tried googling the topic but I am just referred to an old Netbeans plugin of that name.
Even the official Netbeans tutorial page only mentions 'Fix Imports'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"fix imports" --- add (and organize) missed imports
"organize imports" --- format the import statements as configured in "Tools" -> "Options", section "Editor": "Language" = "Java" and "Categroy" = "Imports"

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I was just confused by the different wording in Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. That info along with the eclipse formatting plugin are a must have if you want to use Netbeans instead of eclipse and not destroy the code formatting for every body else that uses eclipse.